# Indefinite integral: $\int x(1+2\ln^2x)\,dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm blocked, since I do not know how to start integrating the following integral:

$$\int x(2(\ln(x))^2+1)\,dx$$

It would be a good idea integrate by parts?

Comment: Yes. Why not try integrating by parts, since you think it might be helpful?

Comment: @ Python241820  Consider $x^k Log(x)^2 = \frac{\partial ^2x^k}{\partial k^2}$ at $k = 1$ and observe that $x^k$ is elementary integrated.

Comment: You have to integrate $x+2x\ln^2x$. There is no difficulty with the first term, so basically all you have to do is to integrate $x\ln^2x$. You can do it by parts, it is a standard exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\ln x=t\implies x=e^t,dx=e^t\,dt$

$$\int x(2(\ln x)^2+1)\ dx=\int e^{2t}2t^2\ dt+\int e^{2t} \ dt$$

Now for the first part use integrate by parts

or use reduction formula:

$$\frac{d(t^ne^{at})}{dt}=at^ne^{at}+nt^{n-1}e^{at}$$

$$a\int t^ne^{at} \, dt=t^ne^{at}-n\int t^{n-1}e^{at} \, dt$$

Answer (score 0):

With substitution $\ln x=\dfrac12v$ we have
$$\int x\left(2\ln^2x+1\right)\,dx=\dfrac14\int e^v(v^2+2)\,dv$$
now use integrating by parts!

**Edit:**
Using the formula 
$$\color{blue}{\int pe^x\,dx=e^x(p-p'+p''-\cdots)}$$
where $p$ is a polynomial, so
\begin{align}
\int e^v(v^2+2)\,dv 
&= e^v\left((v^2+2)-(2v)+(2)\right) \\
&= e^v(v^2-2v+4) \\
&= e^{2\ln x}(4\ln^2x-4\ln x+4) \\
&= 4x^2\ln^2x-4x^2\ln x+4x^2
\end{align}

Comment: This works, but why not just use integration by parts on the original integral?

Comment: I think this way makes the integrating by parts easier, @robjohn

Answer (score 0):

with Integration by parts we get $$x^2(\ln(x))^2-x^2\ln(x)+x^2+C$$